# Django: exporting model data to excel file messes up character set

Tags: django, django-models, export-to-excel

I'm trying to export model data to a Microsoft Excel file type (.xls) by using this view:

```
def generate_spreadsheet(request):
    alumnos = Alumno.objects.all()
    response = render_to_response("spreadsheet.html", {'alumnos': alumnos})
    filename = "alumnoss.xls"
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename='+filename
    response['Content-Type'] = 'application/vnd.ms-excel; charset=utf-16'
    return response
```

As you can see, I define the character set as utf-16 which should include all of the extra characters like áéíóú, etc. But when I open the excel document, instead of reading

> Vélez

you read:

> VÃ©lez

Any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set what charset is going to be used for rendering defining `DEFAULT_CHARSET` in your `settings.py` file:

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/settings/#default-charset

Comment: This didn't matter, it didn't change the outcome.

Comment: I that case, check out what is the charset being use in the DB. Did you define the _utf-16_ as the charset for that table? Did you define the DB charset setting in your django project? And as @Etienne says, it will be useful if you show the template code.

Answer (score 0):

`render_to_response()` is probably writing in 'utf-8', not in utf-16.

Comment: Maybe you should show us your template code. Are you creating a real Excel file or a CSV file?